# Getting ng-repeat data object at a particular index in the DOM

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I want to get data at an index in which the message is displayed on the DOM

```
<uib-accordion close-others="true">
    <uib-accordion-group is-open="status.open" ng-repeat="(sender, messages) in messageStructure track by $index">
        <uib-accordion-heading>
            {{sender}} <i class="pull-right glyphicon"
                          ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}"></i>
        </uib-accordion-heading>
        <div class="message-container" ng-repeat="message in messages | orderBy:'time'" ng-model="message.senderID">
            <div class="message-body">
                <p>{{message.message}}</p>
                <span style="font-size: 10px">{{message.time | datetime}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-9">
            <label>Reply: </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="reply" placeholder="Recepient ID">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
            <label style="color: white;">Reply: </label>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control" ng-click="getMessage(messageStructure)">Send
                Message <i class="icon-arrow-right14 position-right"></i></button>
        </div>

    </uib-accordion-group>
</uib-accordion>
```

Example if the data is displayed at index 1 I want the whole array structure at that particular index

I have tried printing out the message structure at the getMessage() function and nothing is displayed

Please help

Here is the data structure being displayed from the backend API

```
var data = {
            "michel@yahoo.com": [ {
                "id":"088b71bc-5b64-4f09-bba4-cf88b3cc598e",
                "message":"Send message 1 to recipient 10782f82-b23b-4cc1-abed-bd6acadca601",
                "senderId":"0063f297-0da6-4c23-9a53-0480c273d177",
                "status":"Unread",
                "time":"2016-05-13T10:30:11.495Z"
            },
            {
                "id":"088b71bc-5b64-4f09-bba4-cf88b3cc598e",
                "message":"Send message 2 to recipient 10782f82-b23b-4cc1-abed-bd6acadca601",
                "senderId":"0063f297-0da6-4c23-9a53-0480c273d177",
                "status":"Unread",
                "time":"2016-05-13T10:30:11.495Z"
            }],
            "richard@yahoo.com": [ {
                "id":"088b71bc-5b64-4f09-bba4-cf88b3cc598e",
                "message":"Send message 3 to recipient 10782f82-b23b-4cc1-abed-bd6acadca601",
                "senderId":"0063f297-0da6-4c23-9a53-0480c273d177",
                "status":"Unread",
                "time":"2016-05-13T10:30:11.495Z"
            },
            {
                "id":"088b71bc-5b64-4f09-bba4-cf88b3cc598e",
                "message":"Send message 3 to recipient 10782f82-b23b-4cc1-abed-bd6acadca601",
                "senderId":"0063f297-0da6-4c23-9a53-0480c273d177",
                "status":"Unread",
                "time":"2016-05-13T10:30:11.495Z"
            }],
        };
```

So when I reply to messages of the first sender I only want to get data at that users index on the DOM ng-repeat section

Comment: What does *"I want the whole array structure at that particular index"* even mean? Should provide some sample data and expected results

Comment: I have just updated it with the sample data

Comment: So since data is one big object you want `getMessage(messageStructure[message])`. try logging that argument to console

Comment: its giving out an undefined as output

Comment: Suggest you create a demo in a sandbox site so we can see and play with the full code. Make it as minimal as possible just to be able to reproduce immediate problem